# Not sure why my code is giving me an "Illegal Format Conversion Exception" error?

Tags: java

I'm pretty sure the error is caused by the last line.. and from what i can tell, it's not pleased that I'm using "%d", variable. But isn't this valid input for an integer?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class total_cost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int TVs;
        int VCRs;
        int controller;
        int CD;
        int recorder;
        double TV_price;
        double VCR_price;
        double controller_price;
        double CD_price;
        double recorder_price;
        double tax;
        {
            TV_price = 400.00;
            VCR_price = 220.00;
            controller_price = 35.20;
            CD_price = 300.00;
            recorder_price = 150.00;
            tax = .0825;

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            {
                System.out.printf("How many TV's were sold? ");
                TVs = in.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("How many VCR's were sold? ");
                VCRs = in.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("How many remote controller's were sold? ");
                controller = in.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("How many CD players were sold? ");
                CD = in.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("How many Tape Recorder's were sold? ");
                recorder = in.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("QTY\tDESCRIPTION\tUNIT PRICE\tTOTAL PRICE\n");
                System.out.printf("%d", TVs + "\tTelevision\t%f", TV_price
                        + "\t" + tax * TV_price + "%f", TV_price);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4011)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2725)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2677)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2449)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2383)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2781)
    at total_cost.main(total_cost.java:37)
```

Comment: Last `printf` call has a format string that consists of single placeholder, which is `%d`, but first formatting argument is a string instead of number expected by `%d`.

Comment: Please indent your code. Also don't post your entire code, but create minimal, but compilable code example which will lets reproduce your problem. And add more details about problem itself, like stacktrace.

Comment: what? the variable TVs is declared to be an int..

Comment: Yeah, the second parameter is an int concatenated to a String, which makes it a String. Or does it? Now I can't remember...

Comment: Ah lol - you add a string to an int? How would that work? And as said %d takes and int.

Comment: Btw, your naming conventions are reversed. Your class name should be `TotalCost` (Capital letters, no underscore) and your variables should be like `cdPrice` or `cd_price` (start with lower case letters)

Answer (score 4):

You pass a String, not an integer. it should be like this:

```
System.out.printf("%d\tTelevision\t%.2f\t%.2f,%.2f", TVs, TV_price,tax * TV_price, TV_price);
```

PS: I took the freedom to format prices with 2 decimal places.

Comment: What's that? Do you mean `System.out`? Be sure to use an uppercase 'S'.

Answer (score 1):

You should decide if you want to use `printf()` or `println()` which seems to be far more suited to you:

```
System.out.println(3 + "\tTelevision\t" + TV_price + "\t" + tax * TV_price + " " + TV_price);
```

With `printf()` you first put the format string in entirety then all the values like this:

```
System.out.printf("%d number %s string\n", 3, "hi");
```

Comment: when I try to use System.out.println instead, it says: "the method println(String) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, double)"
and also "String.out can not be resolved."

Comment: Please read what I've typed. Or at least copy paste or something. Pass ONE and only ONE argument to the `println()` function. Add all your things together.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this exception because of this line:

`System.out.printf("%d", TVs + "\tTelevision\t%f", TV_price + "\t" + tax * TV_price + "%f", TV_price);`

The `TVs + "\tTelevision\t%f"` is trying to do an arithmetic operation because of the `+`.

You should format your output and then provide the values.

Example:
`System.out.printf("%d %s", TVs, "\tTelevision\");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly that familiar with java specifically, but almost all "Print Format"  functions that I know follow a pattern with the format string first, and all of the arguments afterwards.

like so

```
printf("This is a string %d %d %s %f", arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

What you seem to be trying to do is to do both format strings and normal concatenation at the same time.